# Multilevel metaregression in R, "redundant predictors dropped" (metafor)

Tags: r, meta-analysis, meta-regression

First time doing a meta-analysis, and I'd prefer not to botch this.

Out of a set of studies, I have six studies that each have used a pair of measures (on the same participants) that are commonly averaged to one value. However, there are theoretical reasons that it might be better to use these measures separately. I am testing this by comparing whether the effect sizes from measure 1 are different from the effect sizes from measure 2.

So I have 12 correlations from 6 studies, which introduces dependency between correlations from the same study.

Using the `metafor` package, I use `rma.mv` and the `random` argument to account for the dependency:

```
pd <- escalc(measure="COR", ri=r_Pur, ni=n, data=d)
rp <- rma.mv(yi, vi, data=pd, mods= ~ compare, random= ~ compare | source)
```

where the `source` denotes the study, with six levels, and the `compare` denotes the measure, with two levels.

The results I get are:

```
Multivariate Meta-Analysis Model (k = 12; method: REML)

Variance Components: 

outer factor: source  (nlvls = 6)
inner factor: compare (nlvls = 2)

            estim    sqrt  fixed
tau^2      0.0040  0.0634     no
rho        1.0000             no

Test for Residual Heterogeneity: 
QE(df = 10) = 22.9376, p-val = 0.0110

Test of Moderators (coefficient(s) 2): 
QM(df = 1) = 69.7315, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

               estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub     
intrcpt          0.4341  0.0331  13.0975  <.0001   0.3691   0.4990  ***
compareConsEc   -0.2374  0.0284  -8.3505  <.0001  -0.2931  -0.1817  ***

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 


Warning messages:
1: In rma.mv(yi, vi, data = pd, mods = ~compare, random = ~compare |  :
  Redundant predictors dropped from the model.
```

I'm interpreting that there is a difference between the two measures, as the model results row for `compareConsEc` is much smaller than the intercept (it read somewhere that the use of Q statistic is not recommended). However, the warning indicates that a predictor has been dropped, and since the `compare` is there but the estimate for the study-level is not, I assume the study-level was dropped. Yet, when I run the same analysis in `rma` without the random argument, the results are not (exactly) the same, which suggests that it is not *simply* dropping the random argument but doing something else differently as well.

My questions are:

- Is the analysis and syntax correct in principle?
- Reading [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158546/metafor-rma-mv-function-missing-estimates-for-two-levels-of-a-categorical-moder), I interpret that I have too few datapoints to estimate a two-level model. Does that mean that it is simply not possible to take the study-level dependency into account in the analysis?
- If so, does that mean I should run a `rma` without the `random` argument instead, acknowledging in the report that this dependency might confuse the results? (and if so, to which direction?) Or is there a better option, such as an alternative analysis?
- Why are the results from `rma` and `rma.mv` different?
- Is the `tau^2` useful in that table, with a predictor being dropped and the dependency being unaccounted for? Why is the `rho` 1?
- I used REML method, as a default. What would be a good source to the respective pros and cons of different methods?

Comment: What happens if you use random = ~ 1 | source?

Comment: I do not think the post to which you link is relevant here as the OP there had many more levels than you do.

Comment: @mdewey, they did, but with 228 coefficients the answerer mentioned "thousands of data points", which made me interpret that I'd need a multiple of the number of coefficients.
When I use ~ 1 | source, the results are exactly the same. Doesn't ~1 mean "just model the intercept", but the intercept is always modelled if not specifically removed, so there's no difference? And if compare is in the mods, it does not make any difference if it is also in the random?

Answer (score 6):

The warning has nothing to do with anything in `random` -- it relates to the fixed effects of the model (what you specify under `mods`).

What has happened here is that you have read in the data (probably from some external source) and in doing so your `compare` variable turned into a factor (for example, for `read.table()`, the default is to turn string variables into factors -- see `help(read.table)` and especially the `as.is` and `stringsAsFactors` arguments). Then you must have manipulated the dataset in some way so that some levels of that factor no longer occur in the dataset (maybe you deleted some rows). However, the `compare` factor still has those levels (try: `levels(pd$compare)` and you will see what I mean). When you then use that factor in the model, a dummy variable for that non-existent level is created, but since there are no rows for that level, that dummy variable consists of only 0's -- and that variable then gets dropped from the model matrix.

Here is a simpler example to illustrate this:

```
library(metafor)

dat <- data.frame(yi = c(-0.89, -1.59, -1.35, -1.44, -0.22, -0.79, -1.62, 0.01, -0.47, -1.37, -0.34, 0.45, -0.02),
                  vi = c(0.326, 0.195, 0.415, 0.02, 0.051, 0.007, 0.223, 0.004, 0.056, 0.073, 0.012, 0.533, 0.071),
                  alloc = c("random", "random", "random", "random", "alternate", "alternate", "random", "random", "random", "systematic", "systematic", "systematic", "systematic"))

rma(yi, vi, mods = ~ alloc, data=dat)

### delete rows where 'alloc' is equal to 'alternate'
dat <- dat[-c(5,6),]

### but 'alloc' still has 'alternate' level
levels(dat$alloc)

rma(yi, vi, mods = ~ alloc, data=dat)
```

You can basically ignore that warning. Or if it bothers you, just turn `alloc` again into a factor, which automatically drops the unused levels:

```
dat$alloc <- factor(dat$alloc)
rma(yi, vi, mods = ~ alloc, data=dat)
```

Comment: Oh! My factor indeed does have levels that are not present anymore. Thank you! But where is the estimate for my study-level random effect then?

Comment: And looking at my analyses -- which I ran five times for five different sets of correlations -- in three of five rho is 1, and in those three the moderator is significant, while in the two where the moderator is not significant rho is something else. Why is rho (correlation between levels
of the inner factor?) dependent of the significance of the moderator?

Comment: For random effects, you get a variance. This is denoted ``tau^2`` and shown in the output. And since you added correlated random effects, you also get a correlation (``rho``). And there is no inherent relationship between that correlation and the (non-)significance of your moderator.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations this far, I clearly have to study this some more. But if there is no inherent relationship between rho and the significance of my moderator, what does it imply, exactly, that rho = 1? Can you point me to a source that would explain it?

Comment: Ok, metafor document says that "such a random effects component could be used to estimate how strongly different true effects or outcomes within the same study are correlated and/or whether the amount of heterogeneity differs across different treatment types/arms". When I only have two outcomes per study and it is a categorical variable, a pos/neg correlation only indicates which one is higher. So a rho = 1 would mean that in all studies, the outcomes from one measure are higher than the outcomes from the other measure? Or am I completely astray here?

Comment: No, it means that the underlying true outcomes are perfectly correlated within studies (the model coefficients / fixed effects tell you which outcome is, on average, higher). But I suspect that ``profile(rp, rho=1)`` shows a pretty flat likelihood for that correlation component, so lots of correlation values are compatible with those data.